# How create perfect ui with qt creator?

Tags: qt, user-interface, qt-creator, user-experience

I have a tcp server and use it for home automation. I create ui with qt designer using widgets like buttons tabs and slider, but now i want to make it more user-friendly, interact with all devises by their small illustrations on one 2D plan and looks like this:

[image: img]

Is is possible with qt creator or should i use some external tools?
Please, give me an advice.

Comment: There are different approaches to creating GUIs. Some developers prefer using QML to create the picture you are showing. However, if you do not want to change the technology, it is possible to create that in C++ as well. Check out the GUI of this [software](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wl5LScWUAkw&t=1s). I have created it entirely in Qt Creator. Athough it is possible, it took quite some time to layout the items properly. Instead of using layouts you might also position the widgets manually over this picture used as a background.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19939938/qt-creator-how-do-i-add-a-background-image-to-the-qmainwindow) for an example of how to set an image as a background of _QMainWindow_.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19104957/modern-looking-ui-with-qt/19105395#19105395

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modern looking UI with QT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19104957/modern-looking-ui-with-qt)