# Setting a background for Qt Application

Tags: c++, qt, oop, background, codeblocks

I'm creating an app on Qt application, I want to set a background for it and nothing worked, I tried almost all the codes I found, but nothing worked.

Comment: Some more context would really help here. Have you tried googling your problem, have you read the docs? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add a background image to the QMainWindow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19939938/how-do-i-add-a-background-image-to-the-qmainwindow)

Comment: A better question would have shown one example of the code you tried and how it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Make a Qt resource file.

If you create a e.g a board game

.h file

```
class Board {
public:
    Board();

private:
    QImage boardImage;
};
```

.cpp file

```
Board::Board() :
    boardImage{ QImage{ ":/file.jpg" }.scaled(500, 500) },
}
```